# How to manage table row associated javascript (control ID) while do clone the row

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Initially, table has only one `tr` (label/header) and then on click of `add` button click , i create new `tr` which looks as below. and all other consequence click of `add` will clone the last `tr`.

```
<tr>          
   <script type="text/javascript">

       //fetch the value of select picker control and set into hidden field.
       AJS.$('#' + '${field_uid}-resourcetypepicker-new1').change(function () {
           AJS.$('#' + '${field_uid}-resourcetype-new1').val(AJS.$(this).attr('value'));
       });

       //fetch the value of select picker control and set into hidden field.
       AJS.$('#' + '${field_uid}-locationpicker-new1').change(function () {
           console.log(AJS.$(this).attr('value'));
           AJS.$('#' + '${field_uid}-location-new1').val(AJS.$(this).attr('value'));
       });  

    </script>  
<td>

     <input id="${field_uid}-resourcetype-new1" 
           name="${field_uid}" 
           type="hidden" 
           value="$r.getResourceType()" />

   <select id="${field_uid}-resourcetypepicker-new1">       
    <option value="adad"   #if ($r.getResourceType() == "adad") selected="selected"#end >adad</option>
    <option value="dada"   #if ($r.getResourceType() == "dada") selected="selected"#end >dada</option>
    <option value="aadd"   #if ($r.getResourceType() == "aadd") selected="selected"#end >aadd</option>
  </select>
  </td>

  <td>        
   <input id="${field_uid}-location-new1" 
           name="${field_uid}" 
           type="hidden" 
           value="$r.getLocation()" />

   <select id="${field_uid}-locationpicker-new1">
    <option value="Internal(Local)"   #if ($r.getLocation() == "Internal(Local)") selected="selected"#end >Internal(Local)</option>
    <option value="Contractor(Local)"   #if ($r.getLocation() == "Contractor(Local)") selected="selected"#end >Contractor(Local)</option>
    <option value="Contractor(Offshore)"   #if ($r.getLocation() == "Contractor(Offshore)") selected="selected"#end >Contractor(Offshore)</option>          
   </select>
  </td>

  <td>
    <input id="${field_uid}-rate-new1" 
           name="${field_uid}" 
           type="text" 
           value="$r.getRate()" />    <!-- $textutils.htmlEncode($r.getRate()) -->
  </td>

  <td>
    <input id="${field_uid}-effort-new1" 
           name="${field_uid}" 
           type="text" 
           value="$r.getEffort()" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

PROBLEM:
In above stuff, existing javascript that points to specific control id `'#' + '${field_uid}-resourcetypepicker-new1'` means (render ID looks like `customfield-id-111-new1`). Now, problem is, each clone row will have different unique ID for `select/picker list` control. and this javascript will points to first row control only as `AJS.$('customfield-id-111-new1')`. But it should be `AJS.$('customfield-id-111-new2')` then for next row `AJS.$('customfield-id-111-new3')` .

so, what is the best way to write below jquery stuff which can points to each cloned control rather then pointing to first row controls only ? any way through `tr` reference control or any other way.

```
 AJS.$('#' + '${field_uid}-resourcetypepicker-new1').change(function () {
           AJS.$('#' + '${field_uid}-resourcetype-  new1').val(AJS.$(this).attr('value'));
       });
```

Also, in cloned row, it did not include this javascript , do i need to append after clone ?

Please let me know if any more details need.

NOTE: `AJS.$` is equal to `$`. it is used in velocity template file in JIRA.

Thank You

Comment: _"how to add unique id for picker list. Now,it adds unique id for input box only"_ - If you know how to do it for one field, just do the same thing for the other. (Though the code making the input `id` unique is perhaps not doing what you expect: it is appending the value of `i` to the end of the _string_ that is the previous `id`, not incrementing the digit at the end of that string.) Having said that, why do those fields even need ids?

Comment: these are used in JIRA - custom field - velocity template. so ids are required.

Comment: Several problems: What is `AJS`? Your selectors looks as if it contains server-side code. For JavaScript questions you need to show the generated client-side code. You didn't respond to nnnnnn's remarks. Your HTML/JavaScript is badly formatted, making to difficult to read. `width` on a table row makes no sense what so ever.

Comment: `AJS.$`means `$`  . this is in velocity template of JIRA. and to distinguish template variable, needs to use other keyword (jQuery or AJS.$). hope it clears.  its no worries for width or any other things.. i just pasted generated HTML.. need to resolve issue for that three issues which are facing to create distinct ID for both the control (input box and select) in a jquery and also append related javascript with same.

Comment: To get unique ID of cloned `select` control, i able to do this by taking clone object into variable and then do find for both `input` and then `select` then update the `id` property. its resolved. But facing issue about `tr` asscoiated jquery. so, i have updated question with related details.

Answer (score 0):

In light of the updated question, see the following code

```
AJS.$('[id^="${field_uid}-resourcetypepicker-"]')
```

This selector can be used to get any item with ID that starts with `${field_uid}-resourcetypepicker` so you don't have to worry about the last part of the id i.e. new1, new2 etc.

Secondly, your change event will bind to all those elements that are present on page load. But if you create elements dynamically (clone or whatever), the events won't work. You should use

```
 AJS.$('[id^="${field_uid}-resourcetypepicker-"]').on('change', function () {
       ...
 });
```

This will work for all the elements on the page that match the selector